# How to remotely execute a file on a SMB share as a guest

Tags: execution, smb, payload, metasploit

I have a Windows machine I'm trying to compromise and I've managed to gain access to a SMB share as a guest user. Currently, I've uploaded a bind_tcp payload to the share and I'd like to execute it remotely. I am able to obtain a meterpreter shell when I manually log into the machine as guest and execute.

So far, I've tried smbmap, smbexec, and  crackmapexec with no luck using the -x option. I've also tried psexec_command but the I get an issue where it tries to clean up files in the windows directory. Since I am not an admin, the command cannot continue as expected.

What could be some other possible methods to successfully execute this payload remotely?

I feel like it's also important to note that I can connect and list the share using smbclient, but I am not aware of any execution functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have different methods:

Here is a list of tools with corresponding examples how to use it:

From a linux machine:

- WMI / Impackets `wmiexec.py` or `crackmapexec -x 'bind_tcp_payload' --exec-method wmi-exec`
- SMB / Impackets `smbexec.py` or `crackmapexec -x 'bind_tcp_payload' --exec-method smb-exec`
- Winexe / `winexe`
- Scheduling a task / `crackmapexec -x 'bind_tcp_payload' --exec-method atexec`
- Creating a service / Impackets `psexec.py`

From a windows machine:

- Using Kerberos auth / `runas`
- Creating a service / `PsExec.exe` or powershell
- WMI / `wmic`
- perpaps WinRM

You can try some of this tools like creating a service manually to better understand at which step it does not work.

A nice overview of all this can be found in this blog series ([1](https://blog.ropnop.com/using-credentials-to-own-windows-boxes/),[2](https://blog.ropnop.com/using-credentials-to-own-windows-boxes-part-2-psexec-and-services/),[3](https://blog.ropnop.com/using-credentials-to-own-windows-boxes-part-3-wmi-and-winrm/)).
crackmapexec detailed explanations can be found [here](https://www.ivoidwarranties.tech/posts/pentesting-tuts/cme/crackmapexec/).